# how to change data on mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

i have question

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce"),
    "userMappingId" : "6167bf7307fe8867d48970cd",
    "audioUrl" : "abcs2.com/kou.mp3",
    "audioDuration" : 11,
    "dayId" : 4,
    "periodId" : "61652f30919d4616107a4896",
    "ctime" : ISODate("2021-10-14T05:31:53.569Z"),
    "_class" : "org.kou.xixi"
}
```

if i want to change ctime how i read the code ?

i have use this

```
> db.xabs.updateOne({ "_id" : "6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce" },{$set:{"ctime" : "2021-10-13T05:31:53.569Z"})
```

or use

```
db.xabs.updateOne({ "userMappingId" : "6167bf7307fe8867d48970cd" },{$set:{"ctime" : "2021-10-13T05:31:53.569Z"})
```

but my data still cannot change to the new one

Answer (score 1):

Change your _id into ObjectId.

_id: **ObjectId("6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce")**

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce")
},
{
  $set: {
    "ctime": "2021-10-13T05:31:53.569Z"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are finding the record with the id you need to cast the string to `ObjectId` and second you need to also cast the timestamp using `ISODate` like following:

```
db.xabs.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce")
    },
    {
        $set: {
            ctime: ISODate("2021-10-13T05:31:53.569Z")
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: 2021-10-14T15:47:41.455+0800 TypeError: Property 'findOneAndUpdate' of object abxa.xabs is not a function

Comment: @aaaaaajib you can use `updateOne` if it works for you

Comment: TypeError: Property 'updateOne' of object abxa.xabs is not a function

Comment: i got same error

Answer (score -1):

```
db. xabs.update({ "_id": new ObjectId("6167c0c907fe8867d48970ce")},{ $set: {"ctime": ISODate("2021-10-13T05:31:53.569Z")}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

after i use this code i can run it... it is from documentation for mongoDb Shell 2.6.10

thanks for you all for help me for this issue